# Delimiter in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, delimiter

I'm having problem with finding a unique delimiter for excel when I import a bunch of data from csv. I wanted "^;" to be the unique delimiter. However, Excel isn't smart enough to know that I just want "^;" as delimiter NOT IN CONJUNCTION with single "^" and/or single ";" even I checked both "Semicolon" and "Other" (i.e. ^) as well as selecting "Tread consecutive delimiters as one". Is there any way to achieve  that in Excel where "^;" will be the only unique delimiter it has to look for. Or it's just a painful reality we need accept in MS Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Openoffice allows you to specify the separation string when saving your file as .csv.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way of having a multi character delimiter when importing with Excel.

If it's possible with your dataset, I suggest using find and replace to change all instances of `"^;"` to a more common delimiter format. Having done this you should be able to import into Excel easily.